# How to find new result of task every time from Celery worker?

Tags: python, celery

I am new in Celery. I have defined a task like below:

```
@task(name="process_xls_file")
def process_contact_file_task(file_path):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
    sheet_obj = wb.active
    cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row=2, column=1)
    return cell_obj.value
```

But if I change the return value of this method it does not reflect changes unless I start the worker.

```
[2021-03-05 19:20:47,988: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: process_xls_file[8f2e38ed-e94f-4aa0-84f8-b332e49917af]  
[2021-03-05 19:20:48,057: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task process_xls_file[8f2e38ed-e94f-4aa0-84f8-b332e49917af] succeeded in 0.0659001779999997s: 'Name'
[2021-03-05 19:21:16,795: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: process_xls_file[b8153adb-b6c5-4f9d-9177-730f941d82f5]  
[2021-03-05 19:21:16,818: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task process_xls_file[b8153adb-b6c5-4f9d-9177-730f941d82f5] succeeded in 0.019803497000005166s: 'Name'
^C
```

I do not see new results unless I re-run `celery -A contacts worker  -l info`

Comment: What do you mean by if you change the "return value of the method"?

Comment: @2ps I mean changing `return cell_obj.value` to `return "Hi"`

Comment: You mean a functionality like code autoreload? I don't think Celery comes with that. You might achieve it using tools like watchog.

Comment: @kobuz yeah autoloading

Comment: Here's a detailed post about it https://www.distributedpython.com/2019/04/23/celery-reload/

Answer (score 1):

Celery does not support hot-reload (they took this out in v3 => v4 feature).